# How can i replace multiple line from pdf in c# .NET CORE?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, itext

I am trying to replace pdf text and it is working fine. But my issue is it only replace first object of the array and i want to replace content in loop. Please guide me where i am wrong. Here is my code.

```
public void ReplaceTextInPDF(string sourceFile, string descFile, Dictionary<string, string> textReplacements)
        {
            ReplaceText(textReplacements, descFile, sourceFile);
        }

        private void ReplaceText(Dictionary<string, string> textReplacements, string outputFilePath, string inputFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream inputPdfStream = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                using (Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
                    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);

                    foreach (var kvp in textReplacements)
                    {
                        string searchText = kvp.Key;
                        string replaceText = kvp.Value;

                        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                        {
                            var tt = new MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy(searchText);
                            var ex = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, tt);
                            foreach (var p in tt.myPoints)
                            {
                                iTextSharp.text.Image image = CreateTransparentImage(p.Rect.Width, p.Rect.Height);
                                image.SetAbsolutePosition(p.Rect.Left, (p.Rect.Top - 8));
                                stamper.GetOverContent(i).AddImage(image, true);

                                PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
                                BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                                cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                                cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 7);
                                cb.BeginText();
                                cb.ShowTextAligned(1, replaceText, p.Rect.Left + 10, p.Rect.Top - 6, 0);
                                cb.EndText();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    stamper.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle the exception
            }
        }

        private iTextSharp.text.Image CreateTransparentImage(float width, float height)
        {
            Bitmap transparentBitmap = new Bitmap((int)width, (int)height);
            transparentBitmap.MakeTransparent();
            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(transparentBitmap, new BaseColor(255, 255, 255));
            return image;
        }


        public class RectAndText
        {
            public iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Rect;
            public String Text;
            public RectAndText(iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect, String text)
            {
                this.Rect = rect;
                this.Text = text;
            }
        }
        public class MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
        {
            //Hold each coordinate
            public List<RectAndText> myPoints = new List<RectAndText>();

            //The string that we're searching for
            public String TextToSearchFor { get; set; }

            //How to compare strings
            public System.Globalization.CompareOptions CompareOptions { get; set; }

            public MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy(String textToSearchFor, System.Globalization.CompareOptions compareOptions = System.Globalization.CompareOptions.None)
            {
                this.TextToSearchFor = textToSearchFor;
                this.CompareOptions = compareOptions;
            }

            //Automatically called for each chunk of text in the PDF
            public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
            {

                base.RenderText(renderInfo);
                //See if the current chunk contains the text
                var startPosition = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(renderInfo.GetText(), this.TextToSearchFor, this.CompareOptions);

                //If not found bail
                if (startPosition < 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                //Grab the individual characters
                var chars = renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos().Skip(startPosition).Take(this.TextToSearchFor.Length).ToList();

                //Grab the first and last character
                var firstChar = chars.First();
                var lastChar = chars.Last();


                //Get the bounding box for the chunk of text
                var bottomLeft = firstChar.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
                var topRight = lastChar.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();

                //Create a rectangle from it
                var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(bottomLeft[Vector.I1], bottomLeft[Vector.I2], topRight[Vector.I1], topRight[Vector.I2]);

                //Add this to our main collection
                this.myPoints.Add(new RectAndText(rect, this.TextToSearchFor));
            }

        }
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sourceFile = "D:\\Form.pdf";
            string destFile = "D:\\output.pdf";

            PDFEdit pdfObj = new PDFEdit();
            Dictionary<string, string> textReplacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Phone", "Phone" },
                { "Carrier Legal Name", "Name" }
            };

            pdfObj.ReplaceTextInPDF(sourceFile, destFile, textReplacements);
        }
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From your code, You seems to be using  iTextSharp library to replace the text in pdf, But please note that iTextSharp library is no longer actively maintained, So I suggest to use `Itext7` or `IronPDF` library to achieve that.

Here is an example by using `IronPDF` library to replace the text in pdf, Hope it can help you to solve this issue.

```
            string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pdf-test.pdf";
            string destFile = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New.pdf";
            Dictionary<string, string> textReplacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "PDF", "MyPDF" },
                { "Yukon","XXX"}
                
            };

            ReplaceTextInPDF(sourceFile, destFile, textReplacements);

=====================================================================================

public void ReplaceTextInPDF(string sourceFile, string descFile, Dictionary<string, string> textReplacements)
        {
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = PdfDocument.FromFile(sourceFile);

            foreach (var kvp in textReplacements)
            {
                string searchText = kvp.Key;
                string replaceText = kvp.Value;

                pdfDoc.ReplaceTextOnAllPages(searchText, replaceText);
            }

            pdfDoc.SaveAs(descFile);
            pdfDoc.Dispose();
        }
```

**Original PDF**

[image]

**New PDf**

[image]

==============================Update=============================

install `itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter` and `itext7` nuget package

```
string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pdf-test.pdf";
            string destFile = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New.pdf";
            Dictionary<string, string> textReplacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "PDF", "Data" },

                { "Yukon","xxx"}
                
            };

            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(destFile);
            file.Directory.Create();    
            ReplaceTextInPDF(sourceFile,destFile ,textReplacements);
```

method

```
public void ReplaceTextInPDF(string filePath,string destpath ,Dictionary<string, string> textReplacements)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);
            reader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(destpath));
            
            var pages = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {
                var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
                PdfDictionary dict = page.GetPdfObject();

                PdfObject pdfObject = dict.Get(PdfName.Contents);
                if (pdfObject is PdfStream)
                {
                    PdfStream stream = (PdfStream)pdfObject;
                    byte[] data = stream.GetBytes();
                    foreach (var kvp in textReplacements)
                    {
                        string searchText = kvp.Key;
                        string replaceText = kvp.Value;

                        String replacedData = JavaUtil.GetStringForBytes(data).Replace(searchText, replaceText);
                        data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(replacedData);
                    }
                    stream.SetData(data);

                }
            }
           

            pdfDoc.Close();
        }
```

result

[image]

Comment: I am looking for free version. I checked this is a paid version

Comment: @Robin Singh, Check my update in answer, I use free library  itext7 to write a demo. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Hi @RobinSingh, Have it solved your issue now?